# Logic behind OPCUA node IDs

Tags: python, opc-ua

I'm just getting started tinkering with OPCUA, and I don't know much about it at all yet, trying to figure it out.

Anyways, I'm not using any tools other than the OPCUA library on Python. So far I have a server that runs locally and that contains a function that generates data that evolves over time, and a function that plots the data on a graph (matplotlib).  I plan on putting those functions into nodes so that I can call them from a client.

I don't understand how I could access each individual node though, the whole get_node("n=x;i=y") is a maze to me. I understand that i is meant to represent the data type, but what does that mean when I try to access a node? And n? Is that the order the server creates the nodes in, with the first node being n=1?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NodeId is, as its name implies, an identifier for a Node in the OPC UA address space.

You seem to be hung up on the syntax that is commonly used as a String representation of a NodeId. See this post for an explanation of the syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57563116/85927